# Yandex Mapkit и MonoAndroid ошибка в Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, c#, android-sdk, visual-studio-2015, yandexmapkit

Облазил весь интернет, решил задать вопрос здесь. Разрабатываю кросс-платформенное приложение на C# под Visual Studio 2015 Community с подключенным Xamarin.
Но хотелось бы затронуть именно android версию. Хочу интегрировать Yandex карты в своё приложение. API есть. Скачал yandex mapkit для андроида с GitHub, но он для eclipse. Нахожу в NuGet Yandex.Maps. Но установить (конкретно на android проект) не могу, т.к. выходит ошибка:

```
Could not install package 'Yandex.Maps 1.0.4554.1104'. You are trying to install this package
into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain
any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, contact the package author.
```

Решил реализовать по-другому, в какой-то глуши интернета нашел, что можно создать проект Buiding Library и туда засунуть MapKit. Но так и не понял как.

Может кто подсказать, как вообще можно реализовать карты в приложении на этих примерах? И можно ли как-то обойти ошибку с MonoAndroid?